# How to display a score overview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I am busy with a score overview and I was wondering what is the best way to do it.

My first thought is that is would be an UITableView because of all the functionality it already got.
But because of all the functionality it also has it limitation when you want to change the look.

I was wondering what is a better way:

- An custom UITableViewCell what you design your way and that with an plain tableview
- An UIScrollview where every score is an UIView

I think the first one is easier and probably better memory solution but the second one is better if you look at customization.

So I was wondering what you think and if you know some good reading about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional memory / cpu consumption is probably not noticeable, unless you've got more than 100 results or so.

Therefore I'd use a scroll view with UIViews, it's just so much simpler to implement. Additionally it's much easier to add custom behaviour later if you need something fancy.